# Comparing hashes and evaluate each hash

Tags: python, twitter, hash, python-requests, string-comparison

I'm new in Python. I want to do a "changedetector" program. To do this, I'm getting url content from a website. And hashing with some algorithm.(like md5). If our first hash isn't match with the second hash of the website content's. I'm tweeting myself. I will use cronjob. But I can't comparing hashes between them. I have to keep the old hash. And this old hash has to be compare with new hash. But my code can't keeping the old hash. So everytime I executed the code. It's tweeting anyway. I didn't want this. SO I have realtime comparising method. So how to do this? Do I need to create database? or do I need to use array? My code;

```
    import hashlib
    import requests
    from twython import Twython


    link = "https://blablabla.net"
    f = requests.get(link)
    content = str(f.text)
    a= hashlib.md5()
    a.update(content.encode('utf-8'))
    sabithashdegeri= a.hexdigest
    print(a.hexdigest())

    if sabithashdegeri == a.hexdigest :
    twitter.update_status(status='Specified user () hasnt post anything yet')
    else:
    twitter.update_status(status='Specified user () has post something! Check it on blablabla')
```

Comment: You need to store the old has somewhere where you can access it the next time you run the program. Whether it's a file, a database, or whatever doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how to swap these hashes? The new hash will be old hash. And this new hash will be old hash. Soo confusing ?

Comment: At the end of your program you'd save the new hash to a file. Then at the beginning of the program, you'd load this hash from the file and store it in a variable named `oldhash` or something.

Comment: If you are looping continuously then just store the last hash and compare, if you are rerunning the code and certain intervals just save the hash to  a file and load on each run. You could also use `requests.head(url).headers["Last-Modified"]` to see when the page was last modified

Comment: Are you calling the script at intervals or is the code in an endless loop?

Comment: It has to be in an endless loop. It is computing hash but I can't use(and store) old hashes. so I can't compare..

Comment: @OğuzhanKARAASLAN. I added an answer, all you need to do is store the previous hash in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in a loop, just create an initial  hash outside the loop and compare to a new hash inside, updating the prev variable to the most recent new hash:

```
import hashlib
from time import sleep

def hsh(txt):
    a = hashlib.md5()
    a.update(txt.encode('utf-8'))
    return a.hexdigest()

def bot(link):        
    f = requests.get(link)
    prev = hsh(f.text)      
    while True:
        f = requests.get(link)
        sabithashdegeri = hsh(f.text)
        if prev == sabithashdegeri:
             twitter.update_status(status='Specified user () hasnt post anything yet')
        else:
             twitter.update_status(status='Specified user () has post something! Check it on blablabla')
             prev = sabithashdegeri
        sleep(10)
```

I presume you have a sleep in there somewhere to save cpu cycles.

Running the code on the link and replacing the twitter updates with prints:

```
In [52]: link = "https://www.mehmetince.net/"

In [53]: bot(link)
Specified user () hasnt post anything yet
Specified user () hasnt post anything yet
Specified user () hasnt post anything yet
Specified user () hasnt post anything yet
Specified user () hasnt post anything yet
Specified user () hasnt post anything yet
Specified user () hasnt post anything yet
Specified user () hasnt post anything yet
```

Comment: But now it is tweeting " Specified user has post something.." even user didn't post someting. How can we fix this?

Comment: @OğuzhanKARAASLAN, I had a typo, forgot to call hexdigest

Comment: But if I don't call the hexdigest how can I compare the "md5" hashes? It's all about the hash. Isn't it?

Comment: You are calling it now, that was my point, I forgot the parens, have you run the code since the edit?

Comment: I'm calling it now. That's what I have to. Yes, I executed the code. But as I said it isn't tweeting as it supposed to be.

Comment: What page are you parsing?

Comment: It's a blog. "https://www.mehmetince.net/" Maybe the problem coming from the "https" ?

Comment: @OğuzhanKARAASLAN, you can see the output when I run the code with prints, it does what it should.